# Stop the Div Moving When it reaches the Bottom of the Page

Tags: javascript, html

Here I am trying to create some new Divs. When I press the save button, it fetch the data from text area and create a new div in top of the **Add**       Button. That works Perfectly. Then I create some more divs, the **Add** Button reach the bottom of the page. And My need is, the **Add** Button should stop when it reaches the bottom of the page. I don't want to scroll my page. I just need the Created divs should scroll. Not the whole page. Please give some advise. Thank You.

```js
$('.add-list-button').on('click', function() {
  $('.add-list-button').hide();
  $('.list-create').show();
  document.getElementById("SAVE_LIST").focus();

});




$('.save-list').on('click', function() {
  var listName = $('.list').text();

  if (listName !== "") { //////////////////
    $('.list').html("");
    $('.add-list-button').hide();
    $('.list-create').show();
    document.getElementById("SAVE_LIST").focus();

    createNewList(listName);
  }

});

$('.close-list').on('click', function() {
  $('.list-create').hide();
  $('.add-list-button').show();
  $('.list').html(""); ////////////////////////////////

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="create-list" id=L IST style="display: inline-block; width: 250px;  background-color: #e2e4e6; border-radius: 3px; margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 40px; ">

  <div class="add-list-button">
    <b> Add </b>
  </div>

  <div class="list-create" style="display: none; min-height: 80px; border-radius: 3px;  background-color: #e2e4e6;  ">

    <div class="list" id="SAVE_LIST" style="white-space: normal;word-break: break-all; width: 240px; min-height: 35px; border-radius: 3px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; background-color: #ffffff; margin-top: 5px; " contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Add"></div>

    <div style="width: 250px; height: 35px; margin-top: 5px;">
      <input class="save-list" type="button" value="Save" style="cursor: pointer; width: 60px; height: 30px; background-color: gray; border-color: gray; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 3px; vertical-align: top;">

      <img class="close-list" src="public/media/images/icons/cls.png" width="27" height="27" style="cursor: pointer; margin-top: 3px; margin-left: 5px;">

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Consider having the new divs created within a scrollable div.

Answer (score 1):

change your jquery like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $(window).scroll(function () {
      //if you hard code, then use console
      //.log to determine when you want the 
      //nav bar to stick.  
      console.log($(window).scrollTop())
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 80) {
      $('#nav_bar').addClass('navbar-fixed');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 81) {
      $('#nav_bar').removeClass('navbar-fixed');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
 height: 4000px;
}

.navbar-fixed {
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  width:50%;
}



#nav_bar {
 border: 0;
 background-color: #202020;
 border-radius: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="create-list" id=L IST style="display: inline-block; width: 250px;  background-color: #e2e4e6; border-radius: 3px; margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 40px; ">

  <div id="nav_bar" class="add-list-button">
    <b style="color:white;"> Add </b>
  </div>

  <div class="list-create" style="display: none; min-height: 80px; border-radius: 3px;  background-color: #e2e4e6;  ">

    <div class="list" id="SAVE_LIST" style="white-space: normal;word-break: break-all; width: 240px; min-height: 35px; border-radius: 3px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; background-color: #ffffff; margin-top: 5px; " contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Add"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a container class to your list items like this;

```
<div class="listcontainer">
//items
</div>
```

With a little bit styling, the container should scroll whenever the content size exceeds its size.

```
.listcontainer{height:200px;display:block}
```